# Limits to natural convection in a non-infinite medium

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, convection

I'm trying to understand the temperature profile of a fluid in an underground vertical pipe *without flow*. The fluid is subject to a boundary condition of the form:

$$Q = h[T_e(z) - T],$$

where $Q$ is the radial heat flux, $T_e$ is the external temperature, $T$ is the temperature and h is the (conductive) heat transfer constant.

I understand that for large values of $h$ and low buoyancy forces there will be almost no convection, since a raising fluid rapidly stabilizes, while the opposite is True for the reverse (low conduction, high buoyancy). I would like to know if there is a dimensionless number that can be used, or a reference for the subject. The idea is to check if a measurement of T vs z inside the pipe is representative of $Te(z)$ or not (geothermal gradient, in case you are wondering). Assume that the change of density from pressure is much lower than the change from temperature expansion.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Is Q the radial heat flux at depth z?  Is h the radial heat transfer coefficient between the external medium and the fluid temperature at the wall?

Comment: @ChetMiller yes, Q is the radial heat flux and h is the radial heat transfer coefficient.

Comment: First off, $h$ is a convection heat transfer coefficient. Second, your formula lacks a surface area element, like $2\pi R\text{d}z$. (Ctnd.)

Comment: More importantly, your fluid will show *temperature gradients* both along $z$ and $R$. That would make Fourier's Heat Equation (in cylindrical coordinates) your 'go to' equation because these gradients cause **conduction**.

Comment: @Gert There is no need for an area element if Q is the heat flow per unit area (heat flux).

Comment: @Gert thanks for your answer. You can assume R<<z, although for curiosity's sake I would be interested in knowing the formulation for a cilindrical problem. Frankly, I have very little experience in formulating heat problems so I omitted the math. My practical issue is understanding under what conditions measuring an average fluid temperature vs. z I will get something very close to Te vs z.

Comment: What do you think happens if $T=T_e(z)$?  Will there be any convection?  If so, why?

Comment: @ChetMiller yes, because fluid density decreases with temperature. The deeper you go, the lighter it becomes. I understand this is a matter of how fast it heats vs. how fast it raises. But I don't know how I can formulate it.

Comment: Is this being analyzed as a transient problem or a steady state problem?  What are the thermal boundary conditions at the two ends of the pipe?

Comment: Steady state problem. The thermal boundary conditions at the two ends of the pipe are fixed temperatures T(0) = Te(0), T(x1) = Te(x1)

Comment: If $T_e(z)$ varies linearly with z, the temperature profile $T=T_e(z)$ is consistent with no natural convection being present (i.e., only axial conduction).  However, this is not necessarily stable.

Comment: @ChetMiller: if you're having a shot at this, ping me. Always interested heat problems but I can't really see a way forward here.